# preg_replace with function switch error(?)

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to write something like a BB-Code function, which replaces eg. "[itemThumb type=file itemId=33]" with a thumbnail of the selected item.

For this I am using preg_replace in uniText():

```
function universeText($str){

    $str = preg_replace("#\[itemThumb type=(.*)\ typeId=(.*)\]#", showChatThumb("$1","$2") , $str);
return $str;


}
```

because the output of showChatThumb wasnt working, I reduced showChatThumb() to:

```
function showChatThumb($itemType, $itemId){
switch($itemType){

   case 'file':
       $return = "rofl";
   break;
   case 'folder':
       $return = "lol";
   break;
   case 'link':
       $return = "asd";
   break;
return $return;
}
```

But the switch() function somehow doesn't work right with the variable $itemId. When I define $return before or after the switch function it is passed right threw the replace function.
I read that switch sometimes doesn`t work right, so I also tried with if, else if already but it also doesn't work.

But if I write it like this, the right value also will be returned threw the replace function:

```
function showChatThumb($itemType, $itemId){
    return $itemType;
}
```

I am seriously clueless now, thanks for every help

Comment: I doubt that you can actually use a function as `$replacement` parameter for `preg_replace()`

Comment: it works, but somehow the variable that is handled inside the function fools around

Comment: I'd expect that the function is called with empty strings as parameters and that the return value (which would be `null`) is used by the `preg_replace()` function. You can check that with a `default:` action within `switch()`. `preg_replace_callback()`, as suggested by Sudhir seems like a better approach.

Comment: I tried to pass just the strings threw the function and the crazy thing is that if say that the funtion output should be $type and $typeId, it works. But when I start doing anything with the variable $type it doesn't work anymore..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
function universeText($str){
    echo $str = preg_replace_callback("#\[itemThumb type=(.*)\ itemId=(.*)\]#", 'showChatThumb' , $str);
}
$str = "[itemThumb type=file itemId=33]";
function showChatThumb($param){

    switch($param[1]){

      case 'file':
         $return = "rofl";
      break;
      case 'folder':
         $return = "lol";
      break;
      case 'link':
            $return = "asd";
      break;

    }
    return $return;
}
$tes = universeText($str);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($tes);
```